# SHA1 checksum mismatch after first push

Tags: git, corruption

I am facing a fustrating case: I have a local git repo (with several branches). Running `git fsck` everything looks good. Now, I need push this to a server to be available from other machines. So, on my server I run `git --bare init` repo (note that in this server I have other git repos that works fine).

Then, on the local server I `git remote add origin ...` && `git push --all` to push everything to the remote server.
Now, when I go back to the remote server and executes:

`git fsck --full`

I get:

```
[tsif@server myproject.git]$ git fsck --full
error: ./objects/pack/pack-c4f663419de286d46fa66f69cbb8118cb965ecb9.pack SHA1 checksum mismatch
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
error: cannot unpack 9056828a04daaded875fbfaa106cf3e2305fe386 from ./objects/pack/pack-c4f663419de286d46fa66f69cbb8118cb965ecb9.pack at offset 596841
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid distance code)
error: failed to read delta base object d0b8bbbc070eb59e661dcd0a7a1cd314fe4e0ce2 at offset 4072464 from ./objects/pack/pack-c4f663419de286d46fa66f69cbb8118cb965ecb9.pack
error: failed to read delta base object 65a9f2818dc63467a396f6fdc223e0a5499b78f4 at offset 4073883 from ./objects/pack/pack-c4f663419de286d46fa66f69cbb8118cb965ecb9.pack
error: failed to read object 2eff30e60b36a0ad37dbb10725466dc139c2d972 at offset 4239713 from ./objects/pack/pack-c4f663419de286d46fa66f69cbb8118cb965ecb9.pack
fatal: object 2eff30e60b36a0ad37dbb10725466dc139c2d972 is corrupted
[tsif@server myproject.git]$
```

I tried many times to start over creating the remote branch, but I always ending with a corrupted one. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Are both machines running the same operating system?

Comment: The workstation runs OSX 10.9.3 while the server runs CentOS 6.4. I also copied the project from OSX to a Windows 8 machine, pushed from there, but again I get corrupted object in server-side.